# How to pass multiple parameter with same key with different value in Rest request?

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I am using soapUI tool and I want to pass multiple parameters with same key with different values in a REST request. For example:

```
localhost:3030/products?$select[]=Duracell - AA Batteries (8-Pack)&$select[]=description
```

soapUI does not allow to enter same key (`select[]`), it throws error- "property name exists!"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSw0p.png)

Answer (score 2):

Open SOAP UI and navigate the Request Properties, go to Multiple-Value Delimiter and set one value, lets say comma(,)
then in the actual value you can put comma separated values.

In your case `select=Duracell - AA Batteries (8-Pack), description` will be translated automatically to `select=Duracell - AA Batteries (8-Pack)&select=description`